# How to upgrade from APEX 4.2.0 to APEX 5.0.3?

Tags: oracle, upgrade, compatibility, oracle-apex

Currently I do have APEX 4.2.0 installed with some workspaces / projects I already started working on. Since APEX 5 is radically different from APEX 4, is there a way to upgrade and if so, how?

Are there going to be any compatibility issues while upgrading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Download the newest APEX version and extract it
- navigate to the apex folder and open CMD in there
- type "sqlplus" and afterwards login as sysdba (sys as sysdba)
- When you are logged in, type

> @apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/
>   - You now have to wait for a few minutes for the installation to finish

- Afterwards, type

  > @apxchpwd.sql

  in SQLPLUS to change the admin credentials.
- Update images via

> @apex_epg_config.sql C:\rootdirectory\of\where\you\installed\apex

For compatiblitiy, yes, there might be some problems while upgrading, but you can always google the exact problems if you encounter them.

For reference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/upgrade-apex-for-xe-154969.html

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me perfectly. Ran into some compatibility issues but I think those are easy to fix :)